# Webpack React - CSS Loader Issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-clock/dist/Clock.css 1:0
```

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> .react-clock {
>   |   display: block;
>   |   position: relative;

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-time-picker/dist/TimePicker.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> .react-time-picker {
>   |   display: inline-flex;
>   |   position: relative;
>   i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: Can you send us your webpack config (at least the module.rules part)?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve the issue by just replacing the code.

Older

```
{
       test: /\.css$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]}
```

Newer

```
{ test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
```

I was using a css file from the node_modules and it was excluded.

Thanks for the help Guys

Answer (score 0):

You could use css loader for this, Add the following to the rules array in webpack config should be fine:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  // exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
      {
        loader: "style-loader",
      },
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
        },
      },
    ],
},
```